# How to mimize download time for a single .jpg file download?

Tags: python, curl, download, get, wget

I am attempting to download a small image file (e.g. `https://cdn4.telesco.pe/file/some_long_string.jpg`) in the shortest possible time.

My machine pings 200ms to the server, but I'm unable to achieve better than 650ms.

What's the science behind fast-downloading of a single file? What are the factors? Is a multipart download possible?

I find many resources for parallelizing downloads of multiple files, but nothing on optimizing for download-time on a single file.

Comment: I think the TCP protocol doesn't allow for 'multi-threaded' downloading of a single file. The factors are: Your internetspeed, the servers internetspeed, ping between the server and your client. Also for downloading relatively small files like jpegs, I think setting up any eventual multi threaded downloading will take more time than actually downloading the file. Also you can't download any faster if your bandwidth cap is reached anyways (unless your disk write speed is slower than your internetspeed, which is highley unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

It is not so easy to compare those two types of response time...

The commandline "machine ping" is a much more "lowlevel" and fast type of response in the network architecture between two devices, computers or servers.

With a python-script that asks for a file on a remote webserver you have much more "overhead" in the request where every instance consumes some milliseconds, like the speed of your local python runtime, the operating system from you and the remote server (win/osx/linux), the used webserver and its configuration (apache/iis/ngix) etc.